# Convert Span Id from long to String

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, trace, brave

How can I convert a Brave Span id, which I've retrieved from `span.context().spanId()` to a `String` containing its 64 lower-hex encoded bits. Sleuth contained a static utility method, `Span.idToHex()` which did this. Is their a Brave equivalent? `Long.toHexString()` is a candidate, but we saw issues where we had to left pad our string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that since Brave version [5.6.0](https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/commit/ea904c7b31627eaafee6395a65e7986f98b4c99f) there is the [`spanIdString()`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.zipkin.brave/brave/5.6.3/brave/propagation/TraceContext.html#spanIdString()) which `Returns the hex representation of the span's ID`.

This internally uses the [`toLowerHex(long v)`](https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/blob/master/brave/src/main/java/brave/internal/HexCodec.java#L54) in `HexCodec`. This has the current form since version `4.9.0` as far as I can tell. Before that, the method existed since version `4.0.0` but in some different form. This method is `public` and you could use it, however with caution because as the package name hints it isn't public API and I would expect it to be possible to change in future releases.

Other than that I had a look at [Sleuth's `Span.idToHex()`](https://github.com/reshmik/Zipkin/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/Span.java#L366) and see that internally uses the `Long.toHexString()`. It doesn't do anything more.

> Long.toHexString() is a candidate, but we saw issues where we had to left pad our string.

The Brave's `spanId` is an [8-byte number](https://static.javadoc.io/io.zipkin.brave/brave/5.0.0/brave/propagation/TraceContext.html#spanId--). The hex representation is potentially a 16 character string. This string doesn't have to be left padded. This is a matter of formatting the value while presenting it.

For example this:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s", Long.toHexString(Long.MIN_VALUE)));
System.out.println(String.format("%s", Long.toHexString(-1L)));
System.out.println(String.format("%s", Long.toHexString(0L)));
System.out.println(String.format("%s", Long.toHexString(1L)));
System.out.println(String.format("%s", Long.toHexString(Long.MAX_VALUE)));

System.out.println(String.format("%X", Long.MIN_VALUE));
System.out.println(String.format("%X", -1L));
System.out.println(String.format("%X", 0L));
System.out.println(String.format("%X", 1L));
System.out.println(String.format("%X", Long.MAX_VALUE));
```

Would output this:

```
8000000000000000
ffffffffffffffff
0
1
7fffffffffffffff

8000000000000000
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
0
1
7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

These are valid hex values and there is no padding.

If you want it represented with zero padding you may do it yourself as you already do. I would probably do it like that:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%016X", Long.MIN_VALUE));
System.out.println(String.format("%016X", -1L));
System.out.println(String.format("%016X", 0L));
System.out.println(String.format("%016X", 1L));
System.out.println(String.format("%016X", Long.MAX_VALUE));
```

That would print:

```
8000000000000000
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
0000000000000000
0000000000000001
7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Great answer!

Comment: spanIdString() is not in Brave 5.4.3, which I'm using, but still great answer!